# Make Dbeaver always execute queries in newtab

Tags: dbeaver

In dbeaver, it happens sometimes that I execute new queries and overwrite the previous results. In order to fix the issue, I ask if there is any way to remove "Execute SQL statement" and "execute SQL script" button so that the only remaining options are those that open queries always in a new tab:

[image]

Or maybe there is a way to change this behavior globally...